# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: javascript, matter.js, ragdoll

I decided to create a game called Slinky Untangle. I chose to use Matter.JS, Executing the code, I get this

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
> at /script.js:12:21

Here is my code.

```js
let Engine
x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/raw/master/build/matter.js"; document.head.appendChild(x);
var slinky = slinky || {};

slinky.wiggle = function() {
 Engine = slinky.Engine;
 Render = slinky.Render;
 Body = slinky.Body;
 MouseConstraint =
  slinky.MouseConstraint
};
var engine = Engine.create(),
 world = engine.world;
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    wireframes: false
  }
});
```

I am quite new to JavaScript although I known it a lot.

Comment: There is nothing after let Engine.

Comment: I believe error happen on line `Render.create` because you define `Render` inside of `slinky.wiggle` function and it's not available outside of function scope where you try to access to it. You are faced with closure issue. Place all your logic from snippet into one scope.

Comment: Engine never actually gets the create function you're trying to give it. I assume this is because the function is never called.